# findViewById retrurns wrong element?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, textview, findviewbyid

I can't understand why findViewById returns the wrong element, here is the class:

```
public class EventDetailsFragment extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        setContentView(R.layout.event_details);
        Log.d("First", findViewById(R.id.tuxtView1).getClass().toString());
        Log.d("Second", findViewById(R.id.tuxtView2).getClass().toString());
        Log.d("Third", findViewById(R.id.imageView1).getClass().toString());
    }   
}
```

And here is the xml:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/green"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="175dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:gravity="right" >

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_event_image" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tuxtView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />      
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tuxtView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tuxtView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:textColor="#555"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The logcat ouput is:

```
12-26 23:43:20.249: D/First(6789): class android.widget.TextView
12-26 23:43:20.249: D/Second(6789): class android.widget.ImageView
12-26 23:43:20.249: D/Third(6789): class android.widget.TextView
```

So the point is, why do I get a imageview with id R.id.tuxtView2 and a textview with id R.id.imageView1. The application crashes if I want to assign a text value to R.id.tuxtView2, casted as a TextView.

Comment: Try to reload your project, maybe something wrong with R.java, or verify you are calling the good file with setContentView.

Comment: Well documented question. Sorry, no clue why this happens.

Comment: @JeremyD, wow, I was trying everything, for a couple of hours, except  restarting eclipse. I restarted eclipse and it suddenly worked again. I thought I was doing something wrong in my code. Post that as an answer and I'l vote you up + mark it as solved. Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes you need to "clean" your project when Eclipse mixes up all ids in R.java

Comment: @jonepatr yes sometimes eclipse is kind of stupid :D

Comment: very strange behaviour, tried all the suggestions mentioned and the one that worked for involved moving the elements around in the XML. i.e. I moved the correct element above the incorrect element that eclipse would show in the xml.

Comment: I wonder if a simple grade sync would fix this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try to reload your project, maybe something wrong with R.java, or verify you are calling the good file with setContentView.

By refreshing/cleaning your project the R.java file will be reloaded and will find the named widgets.

Comment: I'll just piggyback on this answer since you're correct, but I'll add that for me deleting the contents of my /gen folder was the only way to resolve a very similar issue.

Comment: Thank you! It's very scary when Google's code claims that "1 == 2" ;)

Comment: NB: do not do what I did and delete your /gen folder -- be careful to only delete the CONTENTS of it. If you delete the whole thing, it temporarily breaks ADT (but you get an error telling you how to fix it, which is fine), but permanently breaks SVN (if you're using SVN). Ugh. Only solution is to "revert" the folder in SVN.

Comment: Strange but I renamed my id (in XML, not GUI view, and then fixed the names where it showed error). It fixed the bug for me. Quite shocking to know Google has still unable to fix these annoying bugs.

Answer (score 2):

I copied your code and made a dummy app. I got these results:

```
12-27 00:03:48.332: D/First(9165): class android.widget.TextView
12-27 00:03:48.332: D/Second(9165): class android.widget.TextView
12-27 00:03:48.332: D/Third(9165): class android.widget.ImageView
```

Apparently there is nothing wrong with the code

Comment: Thanks, I tried everything except restarting eclipse, which turned out to be the source of the problem. Thanks for taking your time : )

Comment: No problem. Next time you could try right clicking on your project and selecting Android Tools->Fix Project Properties OR go under Eclipse bar Project->Clean Project

Answer (score 0):

I've tried almost everything here, but nothing worked until I added a new component to the activity and, after running, noticing that the new component didn't show. It suggested my app wasn't updating with the runs. It worked by manually uninstalling the old version of the app an then running again.